# android add ListView to windowmanager, can not remove the last item

Tags: android, listview, window-managers

I want to display listview in windowmanager.

By add listview to windowmanager.  I have the view overlay in screen then when add,edit, delete item I will only work with adapter and notifydatasetchanged() method.

But I get problem, when delete the last item, I saw the log that delete success, but THIS ITEM STILL DISPLAY IN DESKTOP, although I remove the Listview from windowmanager, I do not know why it is?

here is my code:

Add listview :

```
 private void addNotificationView(final Context context) {
        if (windowManager == null)
            windowManager = (WindowManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        // NotificationView[messageNumber] =
        // LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
        // R.layout.fr_alert, null);
        lv = new ListView(context);
        if (messageNumber == 0) {
            lv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            lv.requestLayout();
            lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            data.add(messageNumber + " <(^OO^)>");
            adapter = new NotifyView(context, data);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            data.add(messageNumber + " <(^OO^)>");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        // | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;
        // Logger.error("y asix: " + (messageNumber * notifyHeight));
        //
        ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .addView(lv, params);
        messageNumber++;
        Logger.error("Added View");
    }
```

Adapter:

```
        @Override
        public android.view.View getView(final int pos,
                android.view.View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                        R.layout.fr_alert, parent, false);

            LinearLayout lnl = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.bgTextContent);
            lnl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            lnl.setAlpha((float) 0.9);
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
            tv.setText("<(^OO^)> " + data.get(pos));
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            TextView tvDelete = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvDelete);

            tvDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (adapter.getCount() != 1) {
                        data.remove(pos);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        // adapter = null;
                        messageNumber = 0;
                        destroynotification(mContext);
                    }
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
```

Then when Adapter size = 0. I remove the listview, But it not woring too :(

```
private void destroynotification(Context context) {
        if (lv != null) {
            ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                    .removeView(lv);
            Logger.error("Removed View, mess number = " + messageNumber);
        }
    }
```

Please see the image, I clicked to delete the last item, the log show the destroyNotication() method is called. But this item still display here :(.
 [image]

Comment: when you add the listview to the windowmanager?

Comment: when the first time (count =0 ) I create listview and add to windowmanager. after i only add data to adapter and call Notifydatasetchanged() method. Please see my update code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you are creating new listview every time,

```
 lv = new ListView(context);
        if (messageNumber == 0) {
            lv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            lv.requestLayout();
            lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            data.add(messageNumber + " <(^OO^)>");
            adapter = new NotifyView(context, data);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            data.add(messageNumber + " <(^OO^)>");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

change to this:

```
    if (messageNumber == 0) {
lv = new ListView(context);
            lv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            lv.requestLayout();
            lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            data.add(messageNumber + " <(^OO^)>");
            adapter = new NotifyView(context, data);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            data.add(messageNumber + " <(^OO^)>");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

means create one list view and add items to the list view, if you want to remove the list view use your code. like this:

```
private void destroynotification(Context context) {
        if (lv != null) {
            ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                    .removeView(lv);
            Logger.error("Removed View, mess number = " + messageNumber);
        }
    }
```

**CONCLUSION:**
you are creating one list view and add the that to window manager. but you are removing different view from the window manager, that is the problem.